# Unable to call modelMap in JSP

Tags: spring, jsp

I have a Spring MVC controller which maps test to test.jsp. It has ModelMap object which has to be accessed by JSP page.
Here is controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public String test(ModelMap map) 
{
    map.addAttribute("data","the string which should bbe printed");
    return "test";
}
```

Here is test.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <c:out value="${data}" />
  </body>
</html>
```

I am getting nothing on the screen.
Please help me out.

Comment: What is the URL you are calling?

Comment: the url is "baseURL/test"

Comment: Is this redirecting to the test.jsp page and nothing is displayed on the screen. Is that the case or the flow is not even come to test.jsp

Comment: it is going to test.jsp as the title is changing. 
After adding `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`
"${data}" is displayed

Comment: so it is not the problem with spring controller or ModelMap. It is the problem of not adding the taglib in jsp.

Comment: Yes. I think the Spring is okay. But problem is in with JSP. I could be wrong.

Comment: If you are using maven then make sure to load the dependencies corresponding to 'jstl' added. Otherwise add it manually to your lib.